# SQL select from two tabels wrong result

Tags: sql

I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

My array:

> ps_product

| id_product | active |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

and

> ps_product_sync

| id_product | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |

and my SQL code

```
SELECT pr_product.id_product, pr_product.active
FROM pr_product, pr_product_sync
WHERE pr_product.active = pr_product_sync.status
```

I get a result like this:

| id_product | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| ... | .. |

24 rows

I try the same with inner but result is the same, I don't have duplicates in the arrays... I don't understand why I get one row 24 times

PS. all tables looks good before posting/saving

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you query two tables and include both in the `FROM` clause, you create a Cartesian product of these tables. In other words, if one table has 4 rows and the other 6 rows, the result is 24 rows.
It is better to create an `INNER JOIN` using the key of the first table and the foreign key of the second table.

Change your query accordingly

```
SELECT pr_product.id_product, pr_product.active
FROM pr_product
INNER JOIN pr_product_sync
ON pr_product.id_product = ps_product_sync.id_product
WHERE pr_product.active = pr_product_sync.status
```

Of course, you could also compare the Keys in the `WHERE` clause or eliminate duplicates using `DISTINCT`. IMHO the most understandable solution is an `INNER JOIN`.

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the primary key join.
Add:

```
    WHERE
       pr_product.id_product=pr_product_sync.id_product
       AND pr_product.active=pr_product_sync.status
```